# How to add child controls to Label control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I'm making a WebForms user-control on an ASP.NET webpage. It should change its contents depending on the user being logged in or out.
The problem occurs on a post-back after the login form's submit button is clicked. The `Visible` property of `LoggedInLabel` is set to true, and the label's `<span>` tags appear in the generated HTML, but there's nothing between the tags - no child controls markup and no text.

From `LogInControl.ascx`:

```xml
<asp:Label ID="LoggedInLabel" runat="server">
    Logged in as: <asp:Label ID="UserLoggedInName" runat="server" />
    - <asp:HyperLink ID="LogOutLink" runat="server">Log out</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Label>
```

From `LogInControl.ascx.cs`:

```cs
protected void LogInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //(...)
    bool isUserLoggedIn = AuthHelper.isUserLoggedIn(Session);
    LoggedInLabel.Visible = isUserLoggedIn;
    LoggedOutLabel.Visible = !isUserLoggedIn;
    if (isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        UserLoggedInName.Text = AuthHelper.getUserLoggedIn(Session).ToString();
    }
    //(...)
}
```

From generated HTML code (after `LogInButton_Click` handler was called):

```html
<span id="LogInControl1_LoggedInLabel"></span>
```

Using the debugger, I confirmed that `LoggedInLabel.Visible` and `LoggedOutLabel.Visible` are being assigned `true` and `false`, respectively. I don't understand why the contents of `LoggedInLabel` don't appear in the HTML code. Reloading the page fixes the problem, i.e. the contents change to this:

```html
<span id="LogInControl1_LoggedInLabel">
    Logged in as: <span id="LogInControl1_UserLoggedInName">login (Fname Lname)</span>
    - <a id="LogInControl1_LogOutLink">Log out</a></span>
```

I'm really pulling my hair out over this, so I'd be really grateful for some help!

Comment: What does AuthHelper.isUserLoggedIn() look like?

Comment: there is a prolem in `AuthHelper`. I test your all code but `AuthHelper` and worked.

Comment: As the accepted answer shows, the `AuthHelper`'s code was irrelevant. I previously used a debugger to confirm that the final value assigned to `LoggedInLabel.Visible` was `true`, and the control actually rendered itself, but contained none of its child controls. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without being able to see the rest of the code for the page, it's tough to tell, but I think it 'be because you have nested labels and the outer one doesn't refresh until the page does.

Remember that the Label is used as text for an associated input box such as a textbox or dropdown, so it's not really being used properly here.

Try removing the outer label, changing the inner on to a Literal, and then modifying changing the function to something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="LoggedInPanel" runat="server" visible="False">
    <asp:Literal ID="UserLoggedInName" runat="server" />
    - <asp:HyperLink ID="LogOutLink" runat="server">Log out</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Label>
```

and

```
LoggedInPanel.Visible = isUserLoggedIn;    
if (isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            UserLoggedInName.Text = String.Format("Logged in as: {0}",AuthHelper.getUserLoggedIn(Session).ToString());
// Set the logout URL here.
        }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!
I didn't realize the Label control is inadequate here.
The MSDN docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfhhhk72(v=vs.100).aspx indeed point out that the Label is meant mainly for dynamic text, but it's not really stressed that much - i didn't notice.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future: I ended up using a `PlaceHolder` control, which doesn't add its own markup to the generated HTML, and it doesn't cause the problem I previously encountered. The `Panel` control is equally good, but I didn't want any `<div>`s wrapping the contents.